# How to run EventListener in background in a Spring/Kotlin Coroutines project

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

Currently I am using Spring 2.6.7 + WebFlux/Kotlin Coroutines stack in a project.

In a Java project, it is easy to run the EventListener in an async thread like this.

```
@Component
class MyEventListener{
   
   @EventListener
   @Async
   void onOrderPlaced(event) {
   }
}
```

But in the Kotlin Coroutines, the `@Async` does not work, and the `EventListener` dose not accept a `suspend` fun.

```kotlin
@Component
class MyEventListener{
   
   @EventListener
   @Async //does not work
   fun onOrderPlaced(event) {
   }

   @EventListener
   suspend fun onOrderPlaced(event) { // `suspend` does not work
   }

   @EventListener
   fun onOrderPlaced(event) = runBlocking { // works, but did not run this continuation in background like `@Async`
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think is to use application specific coroutine context in your application configuration.

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private val applicationCoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO)

    @Bean
    fun applicationScope(): CoroutineScope = applicationCoroutineScope
}
```

and then

```
@Component
class MyEventListener(private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope) {
   
    @EventListener
    fun onOrderPlaced(event) {

        applicationScope.launch {

            // Do something with the event.
        }
    }
}
```

Something around that line should work for your use case.

Comment: This is similar to `GlobalScope.launch`, but just create a custom scope.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Global.launch is not recommended in most use cases due to leak issue. Will this work for you though?

Comment: This works, but another question, if I used `@TransacationalEventListener` instead, the listener is not called at all.

Comment: `@TransactionalEventListener` only works inside transactional boundary so you will have to add `@Transactional` annotation on the method that triggers event firing.